Mi código entra en recursividad infinita al llamar un metodo
Esta es mi clase padre:
class Base():
  def __init__(self,msg,base_child=[]):
    self.msg=msg;
    self.base_child=base_child;
  def append(self,base):
    self.base_child.append(base);
  def mostrar_msg(self):
    print(self.msg);
    for msg in self.base_child:
      msg.mostrar_msg();

Esta es mi clase hija:
class Arepa(Base):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__("Arepa: Es una comida a base de maíz hecha en SurAmerica por Colombia y Venezuela.");
  def receta(self):
    print("- Harina de maiz.\n- Agua.\n- Sal");

class Hamburguesa(Base):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__("Hamburguesa: Es un pan cortado horizontalmente a la mitad, relleno de carne, lechuga, tomate, cebolla y salsas.");
  def receta(self):
    print("- Pan.\n- Tomate.\n- Cebolla.\n- Salsas.\n- Carne.");

Al llamar a la función mostrar mensaje me entra en recursión infinita:
libro_receta=Base("El libro de receta contiene las siguientes recetas:");
libro_receta.append(Arepa());
libro_receta.append(Hamburguesa());
libro_receta.mostrar_msg();

Este error me da:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 10, in mostrar_msg
  File "<stdin>", line 10, in mostrar_msg
  File "<stdin>", line 10, in mostrar_msg
  [Previous line repeated 992 more times]
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in mostrar_msg
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
Arepa: Una comida a base de maíz hecha en SurAmerica por Colombia y Venezuela.


El error se debe a que el objetos que pasa por defecto solo se crea una vez al crearse la función. En la clase Base definiste como valor por defecto una lista (base_child=[]), esta lista solo se crea una vez y se usa la misma lista como valor por defecto:
b=Base("msg");
b.base_child.append("Lista por defecto.");

a=Arepa();
print(a.base_child);
#Out: ["Lista por defecto."]

Como notaras es la misma lista en las dos clase, y por eso entra en recursividad. Pero si le pasas una lista diferente:
b_1=Base("Primera instancia.");
b_1.base_child.append("Lista por defecto.");
b_2=Base("Segunda instancia.",["otra lista"]);

b_3=Base("Tercera instancia");

print("b_2.base_child: ",b_2.base_child);
print("b_3.base_child: ",b_3.base_child);

Da como resultado:
b_2.base_child: ["otra lista"]
b_3.base_child: ["Lista por defecto."]

Como solución te propongo o usar una tuple y copiarla en una lista al instanciar la clase:
class Base():
  def __init__(self,msg,base_child=()):
    self.msg=msg;
    self.base_child=base_child if type(base_child)==list else list(base_child);

Para que así, se cree una nueva lista por instancia:
libro_receta=Base("El libro de receta contiene las siguientes recetas:");
libro_receta.append(Arepa());
libro_receta.append(Hamburguesa());
libro_receta.mostrar_msg();

Da:
El libro de receta, contiene las siguientes recetas:
Arepa: Es una comida a base de maíz hecha en SurAmerica por Colombia y Venezuela.
Hamburguesa: Es un pan cortado horizontalmente a la mitad, relleno de carne, lechuga, tomate, cebolla y salsas

Otra explicación:

https://www.toptal.com/python/codigo-buggy-python-los-10-errores-mas-comunes-que-cometen-los-desarrolladores-python

